# visual studio code django debug configuration doesn't recognize test files

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-testing

I have a standard project setup where my test.py inside of the app folders.

Like so:

```
django_project/my_app/tests.py
```

When I manually run

```
py manage.py test
```

it recognizes my test files.

When using this debug config, it wont run the tests.

```
Found 0 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).      

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

How can I set them up correctly?

launch.json:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Django",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\django_project\\manage.py",
    "args": [
        "test"
    ],
    "django": true,
    "justMyCode": true
},
```

Comment: the path to the manage.py in the config is correct.
"${workspaceFolder}\\django_project\\manage.py"

I run this config with "runserver" instead of "test" under "args" and it works. So it must be something different. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I used a simple example but did not encounter any problems. I think this may be related to the path of `manage.py` in your `launch.json` file. You can delete the `launch.json` and use the automatic creation in debug to get a new setting.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "test"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
```

My `manage.py` is under workspace like the picture:

[image]

Of course, I have another suggestion. You can try [pytest](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing).